# Why does the java JDK installer ask me to give an installation directory twice?

Tags: java

I am currently setting up a new development environment. Part of that is installing the latest Java 7 and the lastest Java 8 JDK, both of them in both 32 and 64 bit versions. I install these in separate folders with the nomenclature D:\java\Java_7/8.

While installing these, I noticed that I have to select an install directory twice for each install. Each time, I selected the folder as declared above.

Why does the Java JDK ask me an install folder twice?

Comment: Just a note: you shouldn't use the 32bit version on a 64bit machine, this can cause trouble/crashes.

Comment: Why was this VtC for off-topic? i do not believe the java JDK (Java development Kit) is a general computing software or hardware platform. if the JDK is off-topic, then what development kits WOULD be on-topic?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've installed Java, but I'd guess an install directory for the JDK and an install directory for the JRE.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That would be my guess as well, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps it is a bug.   But why do you think we would know the real reason for this behavior?  We are not Oracle employees, and we don't have access to the proprietary sources needed to answer the Question definitively.  (And if we did, confidentiality agreements would apply.)

Comment: *"That would be my guess as well, but I'm not sure"*  - So why don't you try giving different directories and seeing what gets installed where?

Comment: @StephenC Turns out that they were, in fact, for the separate JDK and JRE instances, and that they were not supposed to be installed in the same location. I just had to reinstall them because my build scripts broke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, it turns out that, as Gilbert Le Blanc guessed in a comment, the first one asks for the install directory for the JDK and the second one asks for the JRE.

It also turns out that installing these in the same directory can and will give issues for a number of programs, like Ant and possibly Eclipse. I had to reinstall them using separate locations.

Unlike what Tom said, having both 32 and 64 bit installed does not give an issue, but I uninstalled all but the java 8 64 bit version anyway so programs don't get as confused.